# PHP Preg_match one special characters add

Tags: php

I want to search special characters Hyphen '-' and Dollar '$'  in my string as underscore will we always same in my string. 
string can be uppercase  or lowercase
it should match '-'  and next 2 words and 4 number and Dollar '$'
but i am messing up in special characters Hyphen '-' Dollar '$'  and getting Warning
any help?

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

$line = "ESFEDTH-ZD0099$";
if(!preg_match("(^[a-zA-Z0-9]*)-([a-zA-Z]{2})([0-9]{4})", $line)) {
    echo "A match was not found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was found.";
}
?>
```

result is wrong :
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '-' in /Users/skull/Desktop/php/test.php on line 8
A match was found.

Comment: Your regex needs delimiters. Try `"/(^[a-zA-Z0-9]*)-([a-zA-Z]{2})([0-9]{4})/"`

Comment: Also, looks like your logic is back to front. `preg_match()` return 1 if there's a match, but you're writing "A match was not found" if there was a match

Answer (score 1):

Your question talks about underscores, but the example doesn't include one.

Also, looks like your logic is back to front. preg_match() return 1 if there's a match, but you're writing "A match was not found" if there was a match.

Finally you need to delimit the regex.

```
<?php

$line = "ESFEDTH_ZD0099";
if(preg_match("/(^[a-zA-Z0-9]*)_([a-zA-Z]{2})([0-9]{4})/", $line)) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to escape special characters with \ so if you want scape _ you have to write \_

Regards.